# Alternating background row color for crosstab report

Tags: jasper-reports

I want to get background color to alternate for the rows of a "crosstab" report in *iReport Designer*.

I am putting the condition using the REPORT_COUNT under the style section. But i am getting the error REPORT_COUNT variable not found

I am attaching the screenshot. Please suggest

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In crosstabs you'll need to use $V{ROW_COUNT} instead of $V{REPORT_COUNT}.

See the demo/samples/crosstab/reports/OrdersReport.jrxml sample in the JasperReports distribution for a working example.

Answer (score -1):

This [post](http://jasper-bi-suite.blogspot.in/2016/03/tip-rowbanding-and-column-banding-or.html) is a great explanation of row and column banding in crosstabs.